# Google map API. JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

По клику на карту, получаю результат-массив. в элементе массива есть параметр `formatted_address`, который я вывожу пользователю. Проблема в том, что адреса он в большинстве случаев кодирует и выглядит это так `formatted_address: "33XP+8GQ, Orounda 2779, Кипр"`. Можно ли как то избавится от кодировки (33XP+8GQ), что бы адреса были похожи на реальные? При чем, это жилые области, а не леса, пустыни и т д.

Вот пример, как он нормально выдает адрес `"Papas Villa Nr.3, Agiou Georgiou 14, 8852 Neo Chorio. Paphos/Cyprus, 14, Neo Chorio Pafou 8852, Кипр"`

Я вычитала, что это закодированная ссылка на местоположение, полученная из координат широты и долготы. Коды можно использовать вместо уличных адресов в местах, где адреса не существуют (где здания не пронумерованы или улицы не названы). А как это убрать не найду. Может кто сталкивался и нашел решение? Или есть идея как это можно обойти?

прикрепляю пример ответа

[image: пример как выглядит ответ]

Answer (score 0):

решила вопрос через `includes()`

```
const arrayInfo = response.results[0].address_components
```

потом пробегаюсь по массиву `arrayInfo` и ищу `type` c значением `plus_code`
забираю `value` и вычленяю его из `formatted_address` и подставляю в input